# "file_get_contents" work fine on Linux but on Window throw an error 401

Tags: php, linkedin-api

i'm try to write a function to fetch basic profile of LinkedIn user after already authenticated (i mean got access_token).

```
public function fetchLinkinProfile($method, $resource = '', $params = array(), $access_token) {
    if(empty($method)) $method = 'GET';
    if(empty($resource)){
        $resource = '/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,specialties,num-connections,picture-url,email-address,location:(name))';
    }

    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " .
                 $access_token . "\r\n" .
                "x-li-format: json\r\n"
        )
    );
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource;
    if (count($params)) {
        $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
    }
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    return json_decode($response);
}
```

This function work well on Linux, but on Window it throw `401 Unauthorized` although i enabled `allow_url_fopen = ON` in file `php.ini`. What am i missing?

Comment: What versions of PHP? 32 or 64bit? What http daemon, if any? Does it work from command line?